# Correct URL for connecting to hbase using phoenix in java

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper, apache-phoenix

I have set up Hbase on Pseudo-Distributed mode and have installed Phoenix on it.

I can connect to Phoenix using `sqlline.py localhost` and can use it without any errors. 
then I tried to connect to Phoenix through Java by using the following

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:phoenix:[zookeeper]");
```

as give on the apache FAQs. then I replaced the [zookeeper] with the ip address of my VM on which hbase and Phoenix is set up, but its not connecting..

my zoo.cfg contains only the basic properties:

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/home/hduser/zookeeper/datadir
clientPort=2181
```

my regionservers file in hbase/conf has only `localhost` in it.

What should be the correct URL to connect to hbase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to add the machine with zookeeper in `etc/hosts`as `<ipaddress> machine_name` and then use the machine name in the url for JDBC connection.

Comment: Really took, 8 days !.. no support from community.. :(

Comment: I almost went crazy with it... Community knows jack... :)

Comment: do you know a way to get the schemas, and tables for existing Hbase?

Comment: It has been quite some time since I even touched it, but I thought you can just list the tables and stuff using a command when you run the CLI